# my two way verification using firebase is not working

Tags: java, firebase

I wrote a code to allow user to remain in the main activity if his or her data is already in the firebase database else to go back to final setup activity . that is on main activity start let the app check if the current user is null if the user is null he or she should go to login activity else if the user is authenticated he or her records is being checked to know if he  or her records is in the database if he or her records is not in the firebase database he will be sent to setup activity else if his or her records in the database . he or she should remain in the main activity after writing the code, it only goes back to setup activity when ever I run the app. here is the code.
java android:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    NavigationView navigationView;
    DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;

    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    private DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    Toolbar toolbar;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.Maintoolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Home");
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
    }

@Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        FirebaseUser currentUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if (currentUser == null) {
            sendUserToLoginActivity();
        }else{
            checkRecordExistence();
        }

    }

 public void checkRecordExistence() {
        final String currentUserId = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (!dataSnapshot.hasChild(currentUserId)) {

                    sendToProfileActivity();
                }else {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
    private void sendToProfileActivity() {
        Intent ProfileIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Profile.class);
        ProfileIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(ProfileIntent);
        finish();

    }


    public  void sendUserToLoginActivity(){
        Intent LoginItent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Login.class);
        LoginItent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(LoginItent);


    }
```

Comment: Why was this tagged [tag:html]?

Comment: i used     {
      "rules": {
        ".read": "auth != null",
        ".write": "auth != null"
      }
    }        as my firebase database security rules